# Codename one WebBrowser customize look and feel

Tags: codenameone

My theme is set to use Native as false.

When I use a WebBrowser component specially on an android phone, it shows a Loading... 
(infinite progress) before the page loads the url.

Is there any way to customize this Loader ?

BR,

Sanket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only disable it, its a native dialog. To disable it globally just invoke:

```
Display.getInstance().setProperty("WebLoadingHidden", "true");
```

Comment: Thanks Shai. Is there a compiled list of all such properties. Thanks.

Comment: There are very few of these since this is a very special case. We do have a list of the build arguments of which there are far more both in the developer guide and http://www.codenameone.com/advanced-build.html